# Как в laravel добавить двухфакторную авторизацию?

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

Есть сайт на laravel c авторизацией - Passport. Подскажите, как добавить двухфакторную авторизацию?

Comment: https://www.nicesnippets.com/blog/laravel-8-two-factor-authentication-example

Comment: Думаю мне это не подходит. У меня laravel-passport(jwt)